# How to "pop" several View controllers in UINavigationController Stack?

Tags: ios, view, uinavigationcontroller, release

In my app I'm implementing `UINavigationController`. There are several `UIViewControllers` that are being pushed in the stack.

When I reach the last one, I wish to have (upon a user action) all the UIViewControllers be popped except for the first `UIViewController`. How do I do that?

I understand how to pop the last one, but how do I instruct all the previous ones to disappear as well?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can try the `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:`, `popToViewController:animated:` and `popViewControllerAnimated:` messages of the [`UINavigationController` class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006934-CH3-SW13).

Comment: +1, `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` is what he is looking for.

Comment: this doesn't unload the viewcontrollers on the stack though...what do I need to do if I want to do that?

Answer (score 9):

In your case it is really usefull to use `popToRootViewcontrollerAnimated:` as suggested by Irene, but if somebody need to pop exact number of controllers, then following code can be usefull:

```
- (void) popControllersNumber:(int)number
{
    if (number <= 1)
        [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    else
    {
        NSArray* controller = [[self navigationController] viewControllers];
        int requiredIndex = [controller count] - number - 1;
        if (requiredIndex < 0) requiredIndex = 0;
        UIViewController* requireController = [[[self navigationController] viewControllers] objectAtIndex:requiredIndex];
        [[self navigationController] popToViewController:requireController animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
 TravelViewController *travelView = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:self.navigationController.viewControllers.count-3];
 [self.navigationController popToViewController:travelView animated:YES];
```